# English equivalent of German word "Kampfblatt" (militant publication)

Tags: word-request

The German language has the word "Kampfblatt" (rough translation: "militant paper"), which is pejorative for a (supposedly) politically militant publication, often a newspaper, but sometimes also a magazine. The word is mostly applied to publications seen by the user of the word as staunchly left- or right-wing.

What would be the best choice if I wanted to write something like

> The left-/right-wing *Kampfblatt* Podunk Enquirer published today a ...

The common ENG-GER dictionaries don't have translations for the word.

Comment: We might call such a thing a _"[left/right]-wing rag"_ in the vernacular.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is better than what I've seen as suggestions in forums, like for example "activist newspaper", which without context can be misleading, I think.

Comment: You can use "right wing rag" in full confidence that an English-speaking reader will take "rag" to mean exactly what a German-speaking reader takes from _Kampfblatt_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends how militant you mean. Using a derogatory term like *rag* with a description of the politics, as suggested in the comments with "*left/right-wing rag* works if you aren't describing it as *really* militant. If you are, you might call it a "***radical*** (left/right-wing) (rag/paper/magazine)", or to be even more extreme, actually use the word ***militant*** - it doesn't require it to actually be advocating military action or violence, but it is a very strong term.